# Is Woo Product Add-ons extension suitable for print shop?

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, woocommerce

I have an existing wordpress site with woocommerce installed. We want to allow people to upload images they wanted printed.

I've looked at a few plugins that could work with woocommerce e.g. **WooCommerce Upload My File** but the upload function takes place after checkout and we are wondering if that will put people off using the service (I understand the logic behind it though).

Which leads to my question about the Woocommerce Product Add-ons extension which has a file upload option. Has anyone used it and could it be used in this capacity? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you'd like to give people the ability to upload their files while selecting the item? If so, that's exactly what [WooCommerce Product Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/) can do for you.

[image: WooCommerce Product Addo-ns]

[image: Add to Cart]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Michael, what I'm trying to do is see how feasible it is to offer an online printing service. I've created a variable product with size and quantity attributes. The user selects the print size e.g. 5X7 and the quantity e.g. 5-13, and is shown the price. The user then selects quantity required e.g. 13 photos and should be able to upload 13 images. Is that possible with the plugin? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why not. You can create many add-ons and variables that will help determine the price of the product that's being purchased. Hope that helps!

Comment: yes it does thanks. I couldn't find any kind of demo demonstrating this usage and wanted to check a user could upload as many files as he wanted in more than one go. so if that's workable I'll give it a try.

Comment: @lahive If you could mark my answer and upvote it, that'd be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a similar store to you and after many hours researching and testing plugins (including gravity forms), I think product add-ons is the best approach (and less expensive than Gravity forms).

You will still need to customise it slightly as you will need to assign 20 or so image upload fields per product which will not look very good to the end user. Add a bit of jquery so that you only display the number of upload fields that match photo quantity